# Properly requiring three.js in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, three.js

I tried searching for a solution for this, but unfortunately nothing useful I could find came back.

I'm currently building a new Ruby on Rails application and attempting to include three.js to start practicing using it. In order to test if it was successfully required I'm using my browser console, but receiving the error:
ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

From what I saw on this question: [Most efficient way to get a Three.js project to work in a ruby on rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479057/most-efficient-way-to-get-a-three-js-project-to-work-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app)
I should be receiving a return value.

I've tried both adding the three.js file in the assets/javascripts folder and using the threejs-rails gem here: https://github.com/marvindanig/threejs-rails with no success.

I've made sure to require it in the asset pipeline in the application.js file:

```
//
//= require three
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Does anyone have recommendations on what I should try next? My main issue right now appears that it's not being required correctly.

EDITED: Problem was solved. Turns out I was inheriting from the wrong controller model.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23479278/5948566

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to keep that in mind. Turns out the issue wasn't with the application.js file, but the fact I inherited my route controllers incorrectly. It's responding now and working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the Three.js file and drop it in your assets/javascript folder.
In your application.js make sure you have at the end "//= require_tree ." and it should be working fine. You should remove the "//= require three" line because rails loads it automatically and you shouldn't load anything before jquery and turbolinks or else things won't load correctly. If you want to add it to your project explicitly, add it at the end just before "//=require_tree ."

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to keep that in mind. Turns out the issue wasn't with the application.js file, but the fact I inherited my route controllers incorrectly. It's responding now and working!

Comment: Awesome, maybe update your question to let others know as well.

Answer (score 0):

a.) Include your three.js file in

> "app/assets/javascripts/three.js"

b.) in application.js file write `#= require three`

Make Sure server should be running. refresh the web page and type in web console(F12): `Three`, If it gives return result. it's done.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to keep that in mind. Turns out the issue wasn't with the application.js file, but the fact I inherited my route controllers incorrectly. It's responding now and working!